# execute a vbs every 30 minutes

Tags: email, batch-file, vbscript

I want outlook to email a server every 30 mins in real time. is there a way i can do it in this current code or via batch file? making a scheduled task is unavailable and no third party software

```
set objOutlook = CreateObject( "Outlook.Application" )
set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

strMessage = "Test"

ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
With objMail
    .From = "email"
    .To = "email"
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = strMessage
    .Save
end with

objMail.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
objMail.Display
objMail.Send

WScript.quit
```

Comment: is AT command available?

Comment: yes the AT command is avaliable

Comment: Have you considered looping the script with a [sleep](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wscript_Sleep.html) of `30 * 60 * 1000`?

Comment: How would i implement the sleep in my current code or in a batch file? please give me an example

Comment: See my answer for sleep using batch file. For sleeping in vbscript, use wscript.sleep(30 * 60*1000)

Comment: @user1803052 see below in the answers section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of sleeping with VBScript:

```
Dim waittime : waittime = 30 * 60 * 1000    

do 

    ' Insert your code here

    WScript.Sleep(waittime)
loop
```

Oh, and get rid of the WScript.Quit statement, that will... quit your script!

**EDIT**

Another way to do it *and* integrate the messagebox is using the `WshShell.Popup`:

```
do

    ' Insert your code here

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If WshShell.Popup ( "Sending a mail every 30 minutes" & vbNewLine & _
                        "Press Cancel to stop or OK to send a mail right now.", _
                            waittime, "Automatic mail sender", 1 or 32 or 4096) = 2  Then
        exit do
    end if

loop
```

This snippet will execute the code every `waittime`, it stops when the Cancel button is pressed and it will execute the code immediately when `OK` is pressed.

Comment: how would i add some text saying that it sent the message at the 30 min interval?

Comment: How do you want you message displayed? You can use a [Messagebox](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_msgbox.asp), the [WScript.Echo](http://ss64.com/vb/echo.html) command to output to the `stdout` or go all fancy with an [HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)

Comment: the wscrip.echo is perfect but another last question would be how would terminate this script since as far as i can tell it is running the background and i can not seem to find it running in my task manager.

Comment: @user1803052 If you open your taskmanager, you'll see `wscript.exe`. That is the process that runs VBScripts (and sometimes `cscript.exe`, that depends if you run it as console or as Windows script). Ending this process will stop the script.

Comment: NOTE: If you use msgbox, then the script execution will PAUSE till the user presses OK. Use WshShell.Popup instead. With that, you can have timedout for msgbox. You can also have yes-no buttons with it. Clicking NO can terminate the loop.

Comment: @anishsane Good remark! I added an extra piece of code to integrate the popup functionality with the wait functionality _and_ the abort functionality. The only thing missing is a count down counter :).

Comment: :)
The text seen in popup box, is a static text. I use pop-up text like "will automatically assume answer as YES in 30 seconds".

Answer (score 2):

Either use a while true loop in vbs (preferred), or use a loop in batch file (dirty way).

```
:back
myscript.vbs
ping -n 1800 localhost >nul 2>nul 
REM ping -n is a dirty way of sleeping for system <= winxp
REM for win7+ systems, use command `timeout 1800`
goto back
```

Wscript approach:

```
while true
    set objOutlook = CreateObject( "Outlook.Application" )
    set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    strMessage = "Test"

    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
    With objMail
        .From = "email"
        .To = "email"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Body = strMessage
        .Save
    end with

    objMail.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
    objMail.Display
    objMail.Send
    wscript.sleep(30*60*1000)
wend
```

Comment: as good practice how what would the code look like in the vbs code?