# How to run excel macro periodically and paste updated data into new column

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have an `API` fed into my `excel` which downloads stock prices from a `URL`. Column `A2:A194` is the company name, `B2:B194` are the corresponding stock prices.

I want to create a `macro` which runs every 5 minutes, fetches new prices and pastes them into the adjacent column.

This is what i have been able to achieve so far:

```
[Sub GetPrice()
    '
    ' GetPrice Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
    '
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "GetPrice"

    End Sub]
```

This macro pulls data from the previous column instead of `B2:B194`. How do I change the same?

Eg: At the end of 1 hour, I would want 14 columns to have data: the original 2 + 12 columns with fetched price every 5 minutes.

Comment: so for executing the script every 5 minutes check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251397/execute-a-vbs-every-30-minutes

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of why it's pulling from the previous column.  It's because you are using Offset instead of declaring which columns you want to use specifically.  If you know it's going to be:

`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B194")`

then just edit the macro where it defines that part.

The macros are a great way to get an idea of what is going on in the code, but I'd always edit them to be more efficient or just easier to read. Mainly, because so much of the macros depend on the user clicking and activating cells constantly, which isn't necessary for a value to be inserted somewhere or a function to be executed.  You can also see everything going on in the background very quickly, looking questionable.